# char '0x8' what character is this?

Tags: java, xml, char, hex, special-characters

I have a large amount of data in a database.  When I attempt to read a certain portion of the data and generate some xml and send it to a webservice I get the following exception...

The char '0x8' in 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'.

I'm guessing it is some bad data, as it has worked perfectly for about 7 months but now some user uploaded some new data that seems to have some issues.

Anyone know what character this is so I can just run a sql query and clean it from the db?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `"The char '0x8' in 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'."` really the precise error message?

Comment: the rest of the error message contains customer information that I'd rather not post.

Comment: but other than that it's verbatim? That's strange. Could you post what the reason for the problem was, because such an error message seems rather strange to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

8 is usually a backspace.

Answer (score 10):

The ASCII Character 0x08 (or 8) would be the Backspace character.[ASCII Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the meaning of 0x08 depends on the charset.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert into Binary Base64 while storing data into XML to solve these issues.