# XmlRpcClientException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found

Tags: java, apache, api, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm using Apache XML-RPC library to get bugs from Bugzilla. Calling the service, I receive exception:
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse server's response: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the element content of the document.

Is there a way to understand where exactly mistake is. I located a date of bugs, which causes mistake. But there are a lot of them. Can I print the received xml or make exception more precise?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358522/char-0x8-what-character-is-this

Comment: Hi, thanks, I no that it's backspace, But how to get the reply as a string or get exact location of this character?

Comment: This is a bug reported on bugzilla.mozilla.org [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839023).

Answer (score 1):

Its late but in case someone stumbles upon this.

**Edit:**

I have been on this for two months now and finally I have found a viable solution to the above problem.

This issue occurs because [Bugzilla::Webservice](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html) sometimes, in response to a, remote procedure call, sends an invalid character in the XML response.

When Apache's XML-RPC tries to parse that response, it gives the following error:

> XmlRpcClientException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found

To solve this issue, Apache's XML-RPC Client needs to be extended to clean the response off invalid XML characters before trying to parse it.

Find the source code of **apache-xmlrpc** as an Eclipse project [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/xmlrpc/sources/apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3-src.zip). (Import this project instead of the jar files)

To do this, we first need to extend the `BufferedReader` class to replace any invalid XML character before it returns.

So, add `/apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3-src/client/src/main/java/org/apache/xmlrpc/client/util/XMLBufferredReader.java`, like this:

```
package org.apache.xmlrpc.client.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

/**
 * @author Ahmed Akhtar
 *
 */
public class XMLBufferredReader extends BufferedReader
{
    /**
     * @param in
     */
    public XMLBufferredReader(Reader in)
    {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        int ret = super.read(cbuf, off, len);

        for(int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            char current = cbuf[i];

            if(!((current == 0x9) ||
                    (current == 0xA) ||
                    (current == 0xD) ||
                    ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                    ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                    ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))))
            {
                cbuf[i] = 'r';
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Later, we need to send in the extended `XMLBufferedReader` to the `InputSource` of the `parse` method.

The function `readResponse` in the file `/apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3-src/client/src/main/java/org/apache/xmlrpc/client/XmlRpcStreamTransport.java` needs to be changed to:

```
protected Object readResponse(XmlRpcStreamRequestConfig pConfig, InputStream pStream) throws XmlRpcException
{
        BufferedReader in = new XMLBufferredReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

        InputSource isource = new InputSource(in);
        XMLReader xr = newXMLReader();
        XmlRpcResponseParser xp;
        try {
            xp = new XmlRpcResponseParser(pConfig, getClient().getTypeFactory());
            xr.setContentHandler(xp);
            xr.parse(isource);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new XmlRpcClientException("Failed to parse server's response: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new XmlRpcClientException("Failed to read server's response: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if (xp.isSuccess()) {
            return xp.getResult();
        }
        Throwable t = xp.getErrorCause();
        if (t == null) {
            throw new XmlRpcException(xp.getErrorCode(), xp.getErrorMessage());
        }
        if (t instanceof XmlRpcException) {
            throw (XmlRpcException) t;
        }
        if (t instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) t;
        }
        throw new XmlRpcException(xp.getErrorCode(), xp.getErrorMessage(), t);
}
```

After this extension to the Apache's XML-RPC Client, everything should work fine.

**Note:** The rest of this post, is the initial solution that I posted, which is a workaround in case someone does not want to extend Apache's XML-RPC client.

**Old Post:**

In case you are using the [Bugzilla::Webservice::Bug::search](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#search) utility function with some `offset` and `limit` parameters along with the search criteria.

You would be getting this exception on some specific values lets say `x` of `offset` and `y` of `limit` which you can find out by running in debug mode.

Now call the `search` function by keeping `x` as offset and `1` as `limit` and then loop and increment `x` until it reaches a value of `x + y` as offset while still keeping `limit` as `1`.

This way you will be extracting bugs one at a time and running in debug mode you can determine the exact bug which is causing the exception.

For `x = 21900` and `y = 100` do something like:

```
for(int i = 21900; i <= 22000; i++)
{
 result = ws.search(searchCriteria, i, 1);
}
```

Running this in debug mode I found out that the actual `offset` causing the bug was `21963` so then I wrote code to avoid that specific bug:

```
if(offset != 21900)
{
 result = obj.search(productNames, offset, limit);
 bugsObj = (Object[])result.get("bugs");
}
else
{
 result = obj.search(productNames, 21900, 63);
 Object[] bugsObj1 = (Object[])result.get("bugs");
 result = obj.search(productNames, 21964, 36);
 Object[] bugsObj2 = (Object[])result.get("bugs");
 bugsObj = new Object[bugsObj1.length+bugsObj2.length];

 for(int i = 0; i < bugsObj1.length + bugsObj2.length; i++)
 {
  bugsObj[i] = i < bugsObj1.length ? bugsObj1[i] : bugsObj2[i - bugsObj1.length];
 }
}
```